# Merge two List in java without duplication

Tags: java

**Kindly help me to solve this **

```
    List<String> list1 = {"a","b","c","d","aa","e","f","g"};        
    List<String> list2 = {"a","j","k","l","aa","x","y","z"};
```

in final result i want something like

```
    result = {"a","b","c","d","j","k","l","aa","e","f","g","x","y","z"};
```

Comment: Could you please show your code? What did you try?

Comment: Even setting aside the fact that we usually don't like answering questions where the questioner hasn't made any effort to solve them, I can't tell _why_ the result should be what you say it should be.  Does the order of the result matter?  If so, then what about the inputs makes this particular output the correct output?  The question wouldn't be clear even if you did have some code that you tried.

Comment: i tried `for (String x : list2){
      if (!list1.contains(x))
         list1.add(x);
   }` but answer is `{"a","b","c","d","aa","e","f","g","j","k","l","x","y","z"}` i also tries addall etc but couldnt find the desired result

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use a TreeSet for this as it will not allow duplicate elements.
Iterate through the second TreeSet by adding it to the first one

OR

You could use a list and make use of the method `contains()` and add accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save it in a set since it keeps the unique entries. If you need sort based on keey, you will have to TreeSet...

```
Set<String> mySet  = new HashSet<String>();
mySet.addAll(list1);
mySet.addAll(list2);
```

mySet has all the collection that you need.

Comment: same result it is throwing i want this `[a,b,c,d,j,k,l,aa,e,f,g,x,y,z}` instead of `[a, b, c, d, aa, e, f, g, j, k, l, x, y, z]`

Answer (score 0):

```
for (Object x : two){
   if (!one.contains(x))
      one.add(x);
}
```